# Does BitConverter handle little-endianness incorrectly?

Tags: c#, .net, bitconverter

I'm currently writing something in C#/.NET that involves sending unsigned 16-bit integers in a network packet. The ordering of the bytes needs to be big endian.

At the bit level, my understanding of 'big endian' is that the *most significant bit* goes at the end, and in reverse for little endian.

And at the byte level, my understanding is the same -- if I'm converting a 16 bit integer to the two 8 bit integers that comprise it, and the architecture is little endian, then I would expect the most significant *byte* to go at the beginning.

However, BitConverter appears to put the byte with the smallest value at the end of the array, as opposed to the byte with the least-significant value, e.g.

```cs
    ushort number = 4;
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
    Debug.Assert(bytes[BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? 0 : 1] == 0);
```

For clarity, if my understanding is correct, then on a little endian machine I would expect the above to return `0x00, 0x04` and on a big endian machine `0x04, 0x00`. However, on my little endian Windows x86 workstation running .NET 5, it returns `0x04, 0x00`

It's even documented that they've considered the endianness. From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

Am I being daft or does this seem like the wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I am indeed being daft. As @mjwills pointed out, and Microsoft's documentation explains (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> "Big-endian" means the most significant byte is on the left end of a word. "Little-endian" means the most significant byte is on the right end of a word.

Wikipedia has a slightly better explanation:

> A big-endian system stores the most significant byte of a word at the smallest memory address and the least significant byte at the largest. A little-endian system, in contrast, stores the least-significant byte at the smallest address.

So, if you imagine the memory addresses, converting a 16-bit integer with a value of 4 becomes:

| Address | 0x00 | 0x01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Little-endian | 0x04 | 0x00 |
| Big-endian | 0x00 | 0x04 |

Hopefully this'll help anyone equally daft in future!